# Array of object : value as key of the array?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, javascript-objects

I have an array of objects as below;

```
{
    'data': [{
            value: 1000,
            year: 1990
        },
        {
            value: 1001,
            year: 1990
        },
        {
            value: 1002,
            year: 1990
        },
        {
            value: 1003,
            year: 1991
        },
        {
            value: 1004,
            year: 1991
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to convert the same to the one looks like below object

```
{
    '1990': [{
            value: 1000,
            year: 1990
        },
        {
            value: 1001,
            year: 1990
        },
        {
            value: 1002,
            year: 1990
        }],

    '1991':[{
            value: 1003,
            year: 1991
        },
        {
            value: 1004,
            year: 1991
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there any way for doing the same in Javascript or Angular 4?

Comment: you should really gives some code of what you have tried or you won't learn, we are not here to do your homework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**Array#reduce**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) function to iterate over each item and check if the *accumulate object* does not contain a property with that key, add it, assign to it an array an then push the item into it. If contains, just push the item.

```js
const data = [{
            value: 1000,
            year: 1990
        },
        {
            value: 1001,
            year: 1990
        },
        {
            value: 1002,
            year: 1990
        },
        {
            value: 1003,
            year: 1991
        },
        {
            value: 1004,
            year: 1991
        }
    ];
    
const mapped = data.reduce((acc, item) => {
   
   if(!acc.hasOwnProperty(item.year)) {
      acc[item.year] = [];
   }
   
   acc[item.year].push(item);
   
   return acc;
    
}, {});

console.log(mapped);
```